# Como eu crio uma variável com algumas colunas do meu data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, columns

Eu tenho um data frame com 10 colunas e queria extrair 4 destas colunas pra uma variável. Até tentei fazer uma lista e usar a lista mas o código não ficou clean, eu sei que tem como extrair mas não estou lembrando como, do jeito que estou tentando esta dando erro.

```
variável = dados["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

falando de um jeito genérico foi isso que eu tentei.

Answer (score 5):

Um dataframe do Pandas permite que você crie um "sub dataframe" - uma view do dataframe original, passando uma lista com os nomes das colunas desejadas como item dentro dos colchetes.

Isso é, se seu dataframe está na variável `df` e você quer uma variável separada só com as colunas "nome" e "endereço" é só fazer:
`variavel = df[["nome", "endereco"]]`.

O objeto retornado por essa operação é ele mesmo um dataframe, com todos os métodos e funcionalidades que um dataframe tem - mas dependendo da situação, os dados no nvo dataframe podem ser só uma view do dataframe original, ou uma cópia independente. Na dúvida, se for faze qualquer alteração nos dados no novo dataframe, é melhor fazer uma cópia com o método `.copy()`, para ter certeza que o  `df` original não será alterado.

Aqui, um exemplo completo no interprtador interativo da seleção de colunas de um dataframe:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3,4)] * 4, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     3     4
1     1     2     3     4
2     1     2     3     4
3     1     2     3     4

In [4]: recorte = df[["col2", "col3"]]

In [5]: recorte
Out[5]: 
   col2  col3
0     2     3
1     2     3
2     2     3
3     2     3
```